lifetime of references in Rust, specifically when using dereferencing
fn lifetime_test<'a>(s: &'a String, t: &'a String) -> &'a String {
    s
}

fn main() {
    // let a;
    let mut a = String::from("hello1");
    let b = &mut a;
    let e;
    {
        let c = &b;
        // e = c;  // OK, move
        e = &***c; // OK, but why?
        // e = &*b; // OK, is *b same as a?
        // e = &a; // err, sure, a is borrowed
        // e = &c; // err, c lives not long enough
        // e = lifetime_test(c, b); // OK, because auto-dereference
        println!("{c}");
    }
    println!("{b}");
    // b.push_str("string");
    let d = &b;
    println!("{d} {e}");
    b.push_str("hello2");
    a.push_str("hello3");
    // println!("{}", l);

}

What is the lifetime of e when e = &***c?
Here’s my understanding so far:
b is a mutable reference to a, and c is an immutable reference to b.
I know that dereferencing c three times (&***c) should give me a reference to a (really?). But I’m unsure about how the lifetime of the reference e works here.
I understand that c itself is valid within the inner scope, and b is valid throughout the function. But I’m confused about why e = &***c works while e = &c gives an error (because c doesn’t live long enough).
What’s going on with the lifetime of e when I assign it as &***c? How is it related to b and a?

What is happening here is that you are downgrading an exclusive reference (c, with lifetime limited to the inner scope) to a shared reference (e, which has lifetime limited to your main function scope).
Note that there is a period of time where you have both an exclusive reference and a shared reference to the same object, and that you are subject to the regular mutability borrowing limitations.

Thanks. But why is this e = &*c ok, but e = &c gives error? Makes me confused about the lifetime of *c.

The lifetime of *c is the same as the lifetime of b, which is the full function. While the lifetime of &c is the same as the lifetime of c itself, which is the inner block.

But what is the lifetime of ***c, is it the same as b? Why?

You're dereferencing it down to just b, yeah. That's how the * operator works
